# Is there any difference between getLayoutInflater() and .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Simple "No" answer will calm me.
If there is any difference then what it is?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No

As long as the Activity or Window that calls `getLayoutInflater()` has the same Context that would call `getSystemService()`, there is no difference.

---

**Proof** You can trace the LayoutInflater returned by `getLayoutInflater()` to [LayoutInflater.from()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from%28android.content.Context%29) and you can see this is just a shortcut for `getSystemService()` from the source code:

```
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

Comment: Other proof: ````getLayoutInflater() == getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)```` returns ````true````

Comment: No, ````==```` returns ````true```` because the two instances are the same. If ````==```` returns ````true```` then ````equals()````, if it's (well) implemented, always will return ````true````.

Answer (score 4):

There is at least one situation that only

> getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

must be used instead of the counterpart

> getLayoutInflater

That situation is in an arbitrary object class. For example, I have an instance of class call objectA. In objectA, I want to inflate a view onto the parent view (happen in ArrayAdapter that inflates customized row on the its listview.) In this case, ***context.getLayoutInflater*** does not work since there is no activity or windows associated with the context. Only ***getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)*** is appropriate then.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you define a LayoutInflater.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And `getLayoutInflater()` just gives "quick access to the LayoutInflater instance that the window retrieved from its Context" (from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29)) by returning the LayoutInflater.

Similarly, `getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` is used to retrieve a LayoutInflater for inflating layout resources in this context.

So, actually there is ***NO*** difference between the two.

Source : [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Comment: ["Quick access to the LayoutInflater instance that this Window retrieved from its Context."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getLayoutInflater%28%29) Please don't plagiarize the documentation. Use SO's quote format `>` and cite the source.

Answer (score 2):

NO.

There is no difference at all.