# What is the correct way to get layout inflater in Android?

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

There is a way to get layoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and another way is:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

a third one (when I am in an Activity) is:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

So what is the difference between them?

Note that when I sent the third inflater to my adapter, my application worked. But when I sent the context and created the inflater via the second way, it didn't!

Comment: not much of a difference

Comment: look  for those methods on grepcode so you can understand the differences between them

Comment: Aesthetically, 1st one :) Otherwise, all same.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2212197/187543

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not much of a difference between them.

As doc says [public abstract Object getSystemService (String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

> A LayoutInflater for inflating layout resources in this context.

And for the [public static LayoutInflater from (Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context))

> Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.

You can check this thread [Is there any difference between getLayoutInflater() and .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132370/is-there-any-difference-between-getlayoutinflater-and-getsystemservicecontex)

Answer (score 19):

use outside of your activity

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```

Within your activity

```
     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

[Check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from%28android.content.Context%29)

If you open up the Android source you can see that the LayoutInflator.from method looks like so:

```
    /**
     * Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
     */
    public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (LayoutInflater == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
        }
        return LayoutInflater;
    }
```

and there is no difference

As long as the Activity or Window that calls `getLayoutInflater()` has the same Context that would call `getSystemService()`, there is no difference.

Comment: you made y day, i was searching from last five days but did not get luck with this error, now your solution works fine  @Shyam Deore

Answer (score 5):

The only difference is the context that you use. If the context that you use with `LayoutInflater.fromContext()` or `context.getSystemService(...)` is actually an Activity, it should be equivalent to `Activity.getLayoutInflater()`. If it's the application object, you might have problems inflating views that contain fragments, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think that the `getLayoutInflater()` - Method of Activity is a convenience - method.

Remember that `Activity` subclasses `Context`, so all of the Methods available within `Context` are also available in the `Activity` Class.

Internally there will be a call to `LayoutInflater.fromContext()` or `context.getSystemService()`, so I would stick to `context.getSystemService` both to avoid the unnecessary method call as well to clarify that I am making a call to a system service.